# How do I create a method for changing forms easily?

Tags: c#, methods

```
private void administrativeToolsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     administrativeTools addAdminstrativetoolsForm = new administrativeTools();
     addAdminstrativetoolsForm.Owner = this   
     addAdminstrativetoolsForm.Show(); 
     this.Hide
     addAdminstrativetoolsForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
}

public Form changeForm(Form ID);
{
     ID addIDForm = new ID();
     addIDForm.Owner = this;
     addIDForm.Show(); 
     this.Hide();  
     addIDForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
}
```

The first section of the code is my form changing, I tried to create it as a method so I don't have to write it out, I have very clearly done it wrong!

P.S I have never understood fully method creation/declaration and ID is the name/variable I tried to assign the Form

Comment: Is there a main form and a "child" form here, i.e. a dialog? Or are you switching to the other form completely, never to go back to the original form?

Comment: I simply hide the form, create the new one and then to switch back I use hide the form and display the owner - Does that make sense?

Comment: That is a very unusual way of switching forms. If you temporarily show another window such as a settings window, and then return to the main window, that is called a *dialog* and you should used `ShowDialog()` to do that.

Comment: I only began C# a short while and this was a school-based approach to doing it and okay, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx), you will find methods such as:

```
ShowDialog();
Close();
```

First one will open new dialog for you, the second one will close it for you

Comment: Thank you however I have to create a method for class purposes

Comment: Yes, in the method you create the form, show it (Using ShowDialog) and when the dialog closes, you are back where you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
private void SwitchForm(Form theOtherForm)
{
    this.Hide();
    theOtherForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}
```

You can call it anyway you want.

To set it as an eventhandler do something like:

`button1.Click += (sender, e) => SwitchForm(anoterForm)`